# After watching TV, he went out. Is the word watching a gerund or a present participle in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

After watching TV, he went out. Is the word watching a gerund or a present participle? Gerunds follow prepositions as objects of the preposition, but in the above sentence seems like a present participle.

Answer (score 1):

"After" is a preposition there. Its object is the gerund phrase "watching tv". The whole preposition phrase acts as an adverb specifying when he went out.